# Rails, I have used the "--skip-sprockets" flag, how to activate sprockets again?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, asset-pipeline, sprockets

I have been working in a Rails project that was created with the flag `--skip-sprockets` (I hope the reasons for haven done this are not relevant).

Now I want to activate *sprockets* for this project, how can I reverse what this flag has done?

I'm on Rails 3.2.11

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The flag `--skip-sprockets` simply disables the Asset Pipeline for your newly created app. To reverse this, you need to enable the Asset Pipeline. Follow the Rails guide on the topic, it's well written:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

Another solution is to generate a new app without that flag, and compare it with your current app. Copy over all differences related to the Asset Pipeline (it should be mainly differences in the Gemfile and some configurations).

Comment: You're right this is the _diff_ between a project created with the flag an another without it http://pastebin.com/Hg7etWZ9